# Microsoft.CodeCoverage.Console.exe not working for C# code which calls C++

Tags: c#, c++-cli, code-coverage

I have a C# project which is calling libraries for C++ projects via C++/CLI. With `Microsoft.CodeCoverage.Console.exe` I am able to get code coverage for underlying C++ code, however, I can't get the code coverage report for C# code itself.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.CodeCoverage.Console.exe collect -o mytest.dll.coverage VSTest.Console.exe mytest.dll` is not working for some reason in this case, but just use `VSTest.Console.exe mytest.dll /Enablecodecoverage` would work. It will generate TestResults folder and inside this folder, it has trx test results and test coverage is under subfolders, can use `Microsoft.CodeCoverage.Console.exe merge *.coverage -r -o out.xml -f xml` to recursively merge all code coverages in these sub folders and generate `out.xm`l report. `[ReportGenerator](https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator)` tool can be used to convert `out.xml` to human readable html report.